# How Do I split a string with parentheses and commas using regex?

Tags: php, regex, pcre

```
"Func(1,2),Func(Sub(1,Func(true)),2),Func(Sub(1,false),3)"
[1] = "Func(1,2)"
[2] = "Func(Sub(1,Func(true)),2)"
[3] = "Func(Sub(1,false),3)"
```

I Have this string. And I have to use pcre-regex to seperate this into X parts. The parts should be splitted at the comma. What gives me the most trouble is the fact that these function-strings could also contain further sub-function-strings. So I guess it's only possible to identify the split-position by counting parantheses.

```
/.*(?=\().*(?=\)\,)/gU
```

All my attempts to solve this problem didn't work.

Comment: know that `.*` catch all type. Be careful with it whenever you use it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using recursive regex

```
(?:\w+(?:\((?:(?:[^()]+|(?R))*)\)),?)+
```

[**demo and some explanations**](https://regex101.com/r/59NWJ7/3)